# android concurrency

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an application that makes a lot of network requests for xml data that is parsed and presented to the user. Best practices dictate to relegate the network request code and parsing to another thread but since the UI elements have thread affinity it's hard to get the information onto the main thread to be displayed. Does anyone know of any good resources for android threading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use the `Handler` class.  When you post or sendMessage with it, it will always execute its command on the thread it was created in.

Comment: use HandlerThread class to create a new thread for use , use runnable on same thread for async task running , it may help you

Answer (score 3):

This Android Developers blog post covers a couple techniques:

Painless Threading: http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this google.io talk about consuming services?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE